# How can I cleanly display a large json file?

Tags: json

I have a json file that is about 200 MB of size. The problem is that the editor displays it in an unclean way, so that it is not possible to see the structure of the json file. Especially as the json file is nested, it would be very important to see the structure. Is there a way to display it cleanly? As information, I am using Windows and I only found commercial apps for this purpose, but I am looking for a free way.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to pretty-print a JSON file. I use VS Code.

Comment: For Notepad++ there are also JSON plugins with pretty-print functionality

Comment: JSON Plugin for Notepad++ has worked. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

use Shift+Alt+F if your editor is Visual Studio Code.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get the message: This file cannot be formatted because it is too large